# Having to set MainPage all of a sudden (C# / .NET MAUI / Shiny Framework)

Tags: c#, frameworks, maui

First and foremost : I am still learning C# / .NET MAUI / Shiny Framework, so sorry if my mistakes look stupid.
So. I'm trying to understand when .NET MAUI or SF (Shiny Framework) starts requiring me to set `App.MainPage` manually. I seem to have simply put a `Button` in a `HorizontalStackLayout`, added another Button inside of it, and *boom*, now .NET MAUI blows up everytime I try to build it telling me I need to either set `MainPage` or override `CreateWindow`, and I can't seem to find a way to roll this behavior back nor where it comes from *(Visual Studio didn't point me to the part of the code that threw the `NotImplementedException`)*, since even rolling the last changes back to how it was doesn't help me get rid of the exception. So now I try to set `MainPage` in App.xaml.cs, and I get another exception telling me it can't resolve `INavigationService` through dependency injection.

I really don't get what's happening at all.

Comment: Did you try it as in [this example](https://github.com/shinyorg/shiny/blob/master/samples/Sample.Push.Maui/App.xaml.cs#L6)? And do not forget to check if you have registered the page and viewmodel as [shown here](https://github.com/shinyorg/shiny/blob/master/samples/Sample.Push.Maui/MauiProgram.cs#L24). BTW: Without any code from you this is only a very wild and blind guess as we can not look through your eyes at your code. Maybe in the future but not for now

Comment: Thank you for replying and trying to help me. I indeed didn't know I could directly set MainPage as a constructor parameter and inject it from there, that's interesting! So I did this thanks to your example : `this.MainPage = new NavigationPage(mainPage);` (tried both with and without the NavigationPage)
And now I'm getting this exception from `MauiProgram.CreateMauiApp()` : `Prism.Ioc.ContainerResolutionException: 'An unexpected error occurred while resolving 'Prism.Navigation.INavigationService''`.

Comment: It is **not my** example - it is the official example from *Shiny Framework* to show people how to use the framework. Look at the git repository, there is another example using Prism Navigation

Comment: Bad wording on my end, I meant your link. I don't see what I do that's so different, my MauiProgram.cs file is more or less the same except I'm using external libraries, but I was already using the same libraries before is started throwing these `INavigationService` exceptions, this bug seems to have appeared out of the blue. Anyways, sorry for bothering you, I think I have too much to learn to understand the origin of my issue and it would take far too long for you to explain everything. It's a shame because everything worked well up until now. Oh well. Thanks again.

Comment: I will repeat my first comment: *Without any code from you this is only a very wild and blind guess* - we can not tell you "change that line to this" because we do not see any line of code you are using. If you want more help, you have to show more code ([minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) - you should know that after more than 5 years on stackoverflow